# How to disable the bell in urxvt?

Tags: linux, terminal, fedora, urxvt, bell

I'm using **urxvt** on Fedora 30, and when I press `^G`, or when I do some other actions, the terminal beeps. How can I disable the beep?

I skimmed through the manpage and found that you can start urxvt with `urxvt -vb` and there will be no bell sound; but it'll issue a visual bell instead (i.e. the terminal blinks), and I don't want that either.

In **GNOME Terminal** there is an option to [disable the bell](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/pref-bell.html.en), but I can't find the equivalent way to do that in urxvt. I've looked up online and tried `xset b off`, I get no errors but the bell is still audible. I've also tried `setterm -blength 0`, but it fails with this error: `setterm: terminal rxvt-unicode does not support --blength`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to disable the bell on GNOME with the command:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences audible-bell false
```

In general, the [PC speaker page from the ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PC_speaker) appears to have a number of commands that can be used to disable PC beeps.